# why scss file does not working in laravel 6?

Tags: css, laravel, sass

i created a website by laravel 6, i am trying to use scss,i install nodjs, so i created an annonce.scss file in root `resources / scss / page / annonce.scss`, i add `@import 'page / annonce';` in `resources / sass / app.scss` file, then I run `cmd npm run dev`, but change nothing and `npm run dev` execute with success.

I don't know if there is something else to forget to add.

**resources/scss/page/annonce.scss**

```
.product-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 120px;
    padding: 100px 0 120px;

    .selected {
        border: 1px solid #979797;
    }
}

.product-section-images {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.product-section-thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    min-height: 66px;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        border: 1px solid #979797;
    }
}

.product-section-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #979797;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;

    img {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .10s ease-in-out;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    img.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.product-section-information {
    p {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
}

.product-section-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**resources/sass/app.scss**

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// pages
@import 'page/annonce';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your annouce file is using the partial scss type for saving (`_annonce.scss`) and not (`annonce.scss`), then go ahead to use your import.

```css
  // pages
  @import 'page/annonce';
```